# Menu displaying in Chrome but not Safari

Tags: html, css

So I am building out a website for a client, and I've come across an interesting bug. The top nav appears in every browser but Safari. The thing is, the links are there, they just are not visible. But the cursor goes to a pointer! This is so strange! Go ahead and take a look, I would love to figure out how the heck that happened.

http://www.51degreessouth.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you have to remove `float` from your `#nav-primary a` & give it your `.menu li`. Write like this:

```
    #nav-primary a{
     float:none;
    }
    .menu li{
     float:left;
    }
```

Comment: +1 float:none make them appear on safari but from up to down not right to left the look has scrambled but  i didnt test .menu li